# Ejabberd Rest-api - Invalid JSON input on Rest-API call

Tags: ejabberd

I'm setting up a ejabberd-19.02 server on windows 10, configuring it to call admin commands through rest-api. I have followed the documentation as in [ejabberd-doc](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/). I am also able to generate oauth token.

```
    http://localhost:5443/oauth/authorization_token?access_token=0GXCPVJa0l3jFH3Yrn9dIZFMftrNTBFa&token_type=bearer&expires_in=31536000&scope=ejabberd:admin&state=
```

But on calling rest-api method, using curl command as in documentation:

```
   curl -v -X POST -H "X-Admin: true" -H "Authorization: Bearer 0GXCPVJa0l3jFH3Yrn9dIZFMftrNTBFa" http://localhost:5443/api/get_roster -d '{"user": "anas", "server": "localhost"}'
```

I am getting message as:

```
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
    *   Trying ::1...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5443 (#0)
    > POST /api/get_roster HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost:5443
    > User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
    > Accept: */*
    > X-Admin: true
    > Authorization: Bearer 0GXCPVJa0l3jFH3Yrn9dIZFMftrNTBFa
    > Content-Length: 7
    > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    >
    * upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    < Content-Length: 20
    < Content-Type: application/json
    < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Admin
    <
    "Invalid JSON input"* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
    * Rebuilt URL to: anas,/
    * Could not resolve host: anas,
    * Closing connection 1
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: anas,
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
    * Rebuilt URL to: server:/
    * Could not resolve host: server
    * Closing connection 2
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: server
    curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 10
```

ejabberd.log says:

> 2019-08-07 13:52:08.201 [debug] <0.841.0>@ejabberd_http:init:151 S: [{[<<"api">>],mod_http_api},{[<<"bosh">>],mod_bosh},{[<<"upload">>],mod_http_upload},{[<<"ws">>],ejabberd_http_ws},{[<<"oauth">>],ejabberd_oauth},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin}]
>   2019-08-07 13:52:08.202 [info] <0.695.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:238 (<0.841.0>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:59208 -> 127.0.0.1:5443
>   2019-08-07 13:52:08.203 [debug] <0.841.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:307 (#Port<0.54>) http query: 'POST' <<"/api/get_roster">>
>   2019-08-07 13:52:08.203 [debug] <0.841.0>@ejabberd_http:process:394 [<<"api">>,<<"get_roster">>] matches [<<"api">>]
>   2019-08-07 13:52:08.203 [debug] <0.841.0>@mod_http_api:process:198 Bad Request: {error,{1,invalid_json}}

I have tried ejabberd version 19.06 and 19.08.

ejabberd.yml

```
language: "en"
hosts:
  - "localhost"

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "#######"
## If you want to specify the port:
sql_port: 3306

default_db: sql

auth_method: sql

certfiles:
  - "C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem"

ca_file: "C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
    web_admin: true
    captcha: false
    tls: false
  -
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    web_admin: true
  -
    port: 1883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"

access_rules:
  local:
    - allow: local
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  muc_create:
    - allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
  register:
    - allow
  trusted_network:
    - allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
      - oauth:
        - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"

commands_admin_access:
  - allow:
    - user: "admin@localhost"
commands:
  - add_commands: [user, admin, open]
oauth_expire: 31536000
oauth_access:
  - allow:
    - user: "admin@localhost"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: admin
    - 100
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@localhost"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: "https://@HOST@:5443/upload"
  mod_last: {}
  ## mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    ## assume_mam_usage: true
    ## default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      ## mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - "flat"
      - "pep"
    force_node_config:
      ## Change from "whitelist" to "open" to enable OMEMO support
      ## See https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2425
      "eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.*":
        access_model: whitelist
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      "storage:bookmarks":
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

Comment: Once you solve that problem, you may face a bug that I've discovered while testing your question: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempt to provide JSON data, but as you can see, curl sends only 7 bytes of content. 7 bytes are only 7 characters, see this example:

```
$ curl -v -X POST -H "X-Admin: true" -H "Authorization: Bearer UsGV4Ap1zHaaNxJNLiYncn9QG5TRXfEW" http://localhost:5443/api/get_roster -d '{"abcde'

.....
> Content-Length: 7
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes
....
```

So there must be some problem in the console or program you use to run curl, which cuts the command line. In this example, as you can see, a good JSON data takes 40 bytes (in my case the problem is that I didn't set admin rights):

```
$ curl -v -X POST -H "X-Admin: true" -H "Authorization: Bearer UsGV4Ap1zHaaNxJNLiYncn9QG5TRXfEW" http://localhost:5443/api/get_roster -d '{"user": "user1", "server": "localhost"}'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x557900f65a30)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x557900f65a30)
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5443 (#0)
> POST /api/get_roster HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5443
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Admin: true
> Authorization: Bearer UsGV4Ap1zHaaNxJNLiYncn9QG5TRXfEW
> Content-Length: 40
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 40 out of 40 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Length: 111
< Content-Type: application/json
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Admin
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"status":"error","code":32,"message":"AccessRules: Account does not have the right to perform the operation."}
```

Comment: I did the rest-api call from python script, i am successfully able to execute the api commands. And continue to use ejabberd19.02 for now.